# Infopath error when accessing form without www

Tags: infopath, error, domain

I have an Infopath 2010 form embedded on a SP 2010 site. When I access the form at the URL www.domain.com/form.aspx, everything works fine. However, when I don't use the www and the URL is domain.com/form.aspx, I get the following error message instead of the form:

> There has been an error while loading the form. A required resource
>   could not be downloaded. To try to resume the download, refresh the
>   page.

Is there some dependency inside the form that I need to change? Or what might be causing this strange behavior?